# play wav files using java

Tags: java, audio, wav

I am trying to play wav files usinf javafx on my raspbery pi, using the java sound library and the code below, i get an error as follow

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian not supported.
```

After googleing around I found that

big-endian audio format is not supported by the raspberry pi soundcard driver, and that i need to change the getAudioFormat() function to request a little-endian format:

```
boolean bigEndian = false;
```

ok so far i figured that i need the following

```
private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
int sampleInbits = 16;
int channels = 1;
boolean signed = true;
boolean bigEndian = false;
return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleInbits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}
```

but where do i call `getAudioFormat()` from the following code.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Audio/athan1.wav");
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( url );
```

Comment: You may want to try using the [AudioClip](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) or [JavaFX MediaPlayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm) to accomplish this task rather than the Java Sound API. It is possible that the high level JavaFX APIs will deal with low level details like endian formats for you so that you don't need to worry about it.  `AudioClip` is a good choice if the wav sound is short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the method signatures in `AudioSystem`([API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html)). There's a method `getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat targetFormat, AudioInputStream sourceStream)`.

Once you have obtained the `AudioFormat` by calling your overridden `getAudioFormat()` (or, cf. below), you should be able to (quote from the API):

> Obtain[...] an audio input stream of the indicated format, by converting
>   the provided audio input stream.

Alternatively to overriding `getAudioFormat()` (because what happens if you want to play other filetypes in the future?), have a look at the first snippet in the question [Conflicting Jar Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17823542/731040), which seems to do exactly what you want without having to override the method, and is also an example of converting audio streams with the above method.

## EDIT

Try this.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Audio/athan1.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url); 
AudioFormat littleEndianFormat = getAudioFormat();
AudioInputStream converted = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(littleEndianFormat, ais);
```

Comment: Thanks. I onlt want to play wav file

Comment: Well, you can then choose either the override or the on-the-fly creation of an `AudioFormat`. Both should work.

Comment: I am a complete noob, i would appreciate if you give me some head start or something, please, i have been stuck for a while